# How Bcrypt makes decryption slow?

Tags: hash, bcrypt

What happens inside the algorithm of `bcrypt` for people to say that it is slow compared to md5, sha1 and sha256 with or without salt?

Comment: `bcrypt` is designed to be slow, that is necessary inorder for secure password hash storage. The point is to make it slow for an attacker to bruteforce passwords. Simpley hasing passwords with MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc, even adding a salt, is not secure, an attacker can quickly bruteforce passwords these hashes against a list of common passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCrypt has a **cost factor**, which controls how many iterations of hashing are done. This cost factor can be increased in future to adapt to faster hardware.

The cost factor will be raised to the power of 2, that means, increasing the cost factor by 1, will double the computing time. Currently a recommended value is about 10-12, depending on your server.

Answer (score 2):

The SHA family of algorithms were designed to efficiently create a hash for large inputs.  `bcrypt`, on the other hand, was designed to perform computationally expensive operations on small inputs (only the first 72 bytes of input are used, though this should be sufficient for most passwords).

More specifically, `bcrypt` uses the input salt and message to perform key setup for a version of the Blowfish block cipher that has been modified to make key setup more expensive.  The algorithm then uses that cipher to encrypt a known plaintext (`OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt`).  This is why there is a 72-byte limit on the input entropy - the Blowfish algorithm has a limited number of subkeys that need to be initialized.

[Wikipedia describes this process in more detail.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)